# How to use custom storage type for liferay 7 forms?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am following this tutorial [CREATING ADVANCED FORMS](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-advanced-forms), but I am not able to understand how to use external database for storing form data.

I cant find any tutorial about this concept. I am using liferay 7 CE.
Also tutorial says that

> developers can implement their own storage types if JSON is not
>   desirable. If they do, the option will appear here in Form Settings.
>   See the tutorial on custom storage types (**not yet written**) for more
>   information.

My question is which service-wrapper to use, I cant understand how to know which Service is being used for forms.

Comment: Questions that ask for documentation/tutorial are offtopic for stackoverflow. Please rephrase your question with steps that you have already tried and a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve, otherwise you risk this question being closed.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to find how to use custom storage type for forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the storage type only when you are creating a new form in the form settings. The JSON type is the default but you can create a new StorageAdapterto create additional types.

Have a look at the [JSONStorageAdapter](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/f99a193be198b1524d56058ebf93e721f89b7b96/modules/apps/forms-and-workflow/dynamic-data-mapping/dynamic-data-mapping-service/src/main/java/com/liferay/dynamic/data/mapping/storage/impl/JSONStorageAdapter.java) to get an inspiration how to develop a custom one. Should be enough to create a bundle put the new class in. Extend the BaseStorageAdapter and implement new necessary methods.

The new class will be picked up after deployment and you should get a new option in the Form settings.