# Add field name+surname+date birthday in form liferay 7

Tags: database, forms, liferay, liferay-7

I would like to add to my Form on Liferay 7, 3 basic self compiled fields so that you can see the name, the surname and the date of birth. In addition, where can I insert these fields? In which file?
I’m using the form with workflow single approver.

Comment: are you speaking of liferays web forms portlet ?

Comment: Yes, correct !!

Answer (score 0):

ok as far as I know the portlet is configured in edit mode ..
 in combination with this

> Note: By default, form entries are stored in Liferay’s database using
>   JSON format. If you navigate to Form Settings (click the Options
>   (icon-options.png) button → Settings), you’ll see that the only
>   storage option is JSON. Keep in mind that developers can implement
>   their own storage types if JSON is not desirable. If they do, the
>   option will appear here in Form Settings. See the tutorial on custom
>   storage types (not yet written) for more information

and that [How to use custom storage type for liferay 7 forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196456/how-to-use-custom-storage-type-for-liferay-7-forms) , I would  look in the database table of `DDMContent` class

- https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-advanced-forms